# longest path in a tree in python

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

So, I have a dictionary which is in tree structure. Well, not entirely tree. But, I have to find the longest path from this tree.

This is the dictionary:

```
{'1:0': [], '1:1': ['2:1', '1:0'], '1:2': ['1:3', '2:2', '1:1'], '1:3': [], '0:1': ['0:2', '1:1', '0:0'], '0:0': ['1:0'], '0:3': [], '0:2': ['0:3'], '2:3': ['2:2'], '2:2': ['3:2'], '2:1': ['2:2'], '2:0': ['2:1'], '3:2': [], '3:3': ['3:2'], '3:0': [], '3:1': ['3:2']}
```

There could actually be many roots. For example, in the key `1:1`, it has two child nodes, of which one is a dead-end (`1:0`). And then `2:1` has a child `2:2`. Also, `1:1` is a child of `1:2`

How can I write this code in python to traverse and find the longest path?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how this tree would look?

Comment: There is no single root. There can be more than one root. So, I'm not really sure if this is even tree or not. :/

Comment: Then you would need to elaborate further, we lack enough information to solve this as is. Could you visualize the graph and a solution?

Comment: So basically, in that dictionary there is one path which is the longest. The dead-ends are marked as empty list. 
I'm trying to visualize, but if I can visualize then maybe I can also find the longest path.

Comment: A tree is a connected undirected graph with no cycles. A rooted tree (what programmers normally just call "tree") is a tree with exactly one vertex designated as its root (this also imposes orientation on all edges). There is no such thing as tree with many roots. A *forest* is a collection of disjoint trees. It doesn't look like you have any of those tree-ish things. Perhaps it's just a generic directed graph?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a recursive version of the breadth-first search:

```
_d = {'1:0': [], '1:1': ['2:1', '1:0'], '1:2': ['1:3', '2:2', '1:1'], '1:3': [], '0:1': ['0:2', '1:1', '0:0'], '0:0': ['1:0'], '0:3': [], '0:2': ['0:3'], '2:3': ['2:2'], '2:2': ['3:2'], '2:1': ['2:2'], '2:0': ['2:1'], '3:2': [], '3:3': ['3:2'], '3:0': [], '3:1': ['3:2']}
def paths(d, _start, _current = []):
  if _current:
    yield _current
  for i in d[_start]:
     if i not in _current:
        yield from paths(d, i, _current+[i])

results = [c for i in _d for c in paths(_d, i, [i])]
_max_len = max(map(len, results))
_paths = [i for i in results if len(i) == _max_len]
```

Output:

```
[['1:2', '1:1', '2:1', '2:2', '3:2'], ['0:1', '1:1', '2:1', '2:2', '3:2']]
```

Comment: upvoted for not using a 3rd party solution but a simple recursive approach

Comment: Examining all paths in a DAG has exponential complexity. Optimally finding the longest path in a DAG has linear complexity.

Comment: If there are two paths which have the same length?

Answer (score 1):

You should consider a different structure to hold this data, this is essentially a graph problem. python comes with a really useful [networkx](https://networkx.github.io/) library for graphs.
You can use [dag_longest_path](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.dag.dag_longest_path.html) to find the longest path in a directed graph.

```
semi_tree = {'1:0': [], '1:1': ['2:1', '1:0'], '1:2': ['1:3', '2:2', '1:1'], '1:3': [], '0:1': ['0:2', '1:1', '0:0'], '0:0': ['1:0'], '0:3': [], '0:2': ['0:3'], '2:3': ['2:2'], '2:2': ['3:2'], '2:1': ['2:2'], '2:0': ['2:1'], '3:2': [], '3:3': ['3:2'], '3:0': [], '3:1': ['3:2']}
import networkx as nx
my_graph = nx.DiGraph(semi_tree)
result = nx.dag_longest_path(my_graph)
print(result) #Output: ['1:2', '1:1', '2:1', '2:2', '3:2']
```